# Laravel execute where condition based on variable null or not

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel. I want to execute my where condition if my variable value is not null. I tried the below code exactly not getting an idea of what to do.

```
$search = $array['search'];
$id = $array['id'];
$Data = Model::where('id', '=', $id)

if($search != '') {
    //I want to include where condition here
}
```

Comment: You wish to include filter based on `id` and `search` or from `search` only?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
Model::when($search !== null, function ($query) use ($search) {
    return $query->where('column', $search);
})
```

Comment: $Data = DB::table('mytable')->where('id', '=', $Id)
                ->when(!is_null($searchBy) !== null, function ($query) use ($searchBy) {
                    return $query->where('pid', '=', $searchBy)->orWhere('pname', 'like', '%' . $searchBy . '%')->orWhere('ps', 'like', '%' . $searchBy . '%');
                })->get();
As per your answer, i build this query, but it didn't give me the appropriate result.
My query should be like this
select * from table where id=$id AND (pid = $searchby OR pname = $searchby OR ps = $searchby)

Comment: `is_null($searchBy) !== null` will always return `false` because `is_null` returns `true` or `false`. Either use `when(is_null($search), ...)` or `when($search !== null, ...)`. Don't combine them.

Comment: Got it. Can i use multiple conditions in when like this Model::when($search !== null && $search >0, function ($query) use ($search) {
    return $query->where('column', $search);
})

Comment: You can do whatever you want as long as it evaluates to a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$Data` variable is an Eloquent Query Builder object so you can add conditions to it for the query you are building:

```
if ($search) {
    $Data->where('field', $search);
}
```